# Determine plot of flot point

Tags: javascript, unique, flot, interactive, flot.tooltip

I have a flot graph with a few different plots in it.  There is interactivity that triggers an event when a point is hovered over, a la http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/interacting/.  Is there any on-hand way of determining which plot the event's point came from, short of coloring all plots uniquely and getting at the point's color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the script on that page you have this binding for the `plothover` event:

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item)
```

The `item` is the actual point you are hovering over (or null if you are not over a point). That object contains all the data you need including both `series` which gives you the series it belongs to (which I assume is what you meant by `plot`) and `seriesIndex`.

The actual description of the `item` object is kind of hidden in the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-grid):

```
item: {
    datapoint: the point, e.g. [0, 2]
    dataIndex: the index of the point in the data array
    series: the series object
    seriesIndex: the index of the series
    pageX, pageY: the global screen coordinates of the point
}
```

Also note: "The item object in this example is either null or a nearby object on the form"

How near "nearby" is depends on the `mouseActiveRadius`